# broadcast a scalar on Dataframe by multiplying on index label

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following.

Given `df1`:

```
        0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
   BTC -0.000949 -0.002530 -0.004480 -0.005973 -0.004268 -0.005630 -0.007931   
   ETH -0.000701  0.001756 -0.001333  0.000038  0.000101 -0.001066  0.000171   
   XRP  0.000023 -0.000052 -0.000104 -0.003211 -0.003266 -0.008709 -0.010135
```

And `df2`:

```
          2019-10-01
currency            
 BTC         0.000807
 ETH         0.000011
 XRP         0.000109
```

I would like to multiply each scalar of `df2` by its corresponding row in `df1`
For example in the cell of the output dataframe, it would be 0.000807 * -0.000949 = -0.000000766
I tried the following code but it does not work as expected:

```
 w_ret = df1.mul(df2, axis=0, fill_value=0)
```

Any help would be great please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select column by name for `Series`:

```
w_ret = df1.mul(df2['2019-10-01'], axis=0)
print (w_ret)
                0             1             2             3             4  \
BTC -7.658430e-07 -2.041710e-06 -3.615360e-06 -4.820211e-06 -3.444276e-06   
ETH -7.711000e-09  1.931600e-08 -1.466300e-08  4.180000e-10  1.111000e-09   
XRP  2.507000e-09 -5.668000e-09 -1.133600e-08 -3.499990e-07 -3.559940e-07   

                5             6  
BTC -4.543410e-06 -6.400317e-06  
ETH -1.172600e-08  1.881000e-09  
XRP -9.492810e-07 -1.104715e-06
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why do we have to specify the column name when there is only 1 column please? I don't understand the logic

Comment: @mamadede - I think it is for more general solutions - pandas developers create one solution for multiple by `Series` and another for multiple by DataFrames, where is 1 or 2 or N columns. So working with Series and one column DataFrame is different.